# How do you compare file of current branch with file in given commit in VsCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project on a given branch in VSCode, and want to compare my current file with the contents of the same file in a previous commit on a different branch. I think I can do this with the `diff` command, but I want to do it visually in VSCode. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) or [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory)

In GitLens, you can run the editor command "Open changes with Branch or or Tag…". You can open the editor commands by pressing `Control` / `Cmd` + `Shift` + `P`.

Comment: Looking into them. Thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe explain how to do it using GitLens?

Comment: If this is what you are looking for, you can try revision navigation, specifically `gitlens.diffWithPrevious` as can be seen [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#revision-navigation-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure you can do that by default with VSCode. Or I don't know to do that too.
Currently, I use [Git History](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode) extensions to do that.
I go to look on diff file, and click on Git History button on top and select the branch and commit where I want to diff with current file.