# Visual Studio compare file in different branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, rider

I used to work with JetBrains Rider for a couple of years and as a company strategy I'm being forced to go back to Visual Studio. There is a feature that I quite love in Rider that is to easily compare a specific file with it's version in any branch.

[image]

I know that VS2022 can compare files that are already in my computer, and that I can compare commit differences or just use git diff. I wonder if is there anything straightforwarded for files in any branch built in VS, or perhaps an extension, plugin or tool (other than Resharper) that could easily do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you compare file of current branch with file in given commit in VsCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823996/how-do-you-compare-file-of-current-branch-with-file-in-given-commit-in-vscode)

Comment: It does... partially... It definitely helps, but my lazyness was expecting something within Visual Studio. Opening VS Code just to that almost sounds like too much work, but valid if no other option

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought you meant VSCode in the 1st place.